# Delete mail in Gmail domain level multiple users

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, gmail

I got mail from 2013.01.01 and back for about 20 users. It's Apps for Business. I have super admin privilege.

I know how to do this i Apps Script, but it will only do it for me (the logged in user).
I would like to do it for all those 20 users.

Since i can't to it with Apps Script, i Probably have to do it with a real application?
I know a little Java, and I think i could host it on App Engine. But could someone point me in to the right direction codewise, is there any one that have done this before, and do you know if the code is available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible but unless you have experience with oauth and imap it will be hard.
I suggest you just use the apps script you have. Simply publish it to run as 'user accesing the webapp' with a simple webapp interface (a button to start the process basically) and ask each person to run it.